# Strange Python 3 error

Tags: python, attributes, python-idle

I'm pretty sure all of the code is correct; I believe the error may be a mistake with the installation files.

```
a,b = input('Enter in format number^power: ').split('^')
a = int (a)
b = int (b)
result = a**b
print (result)
input()
```

When I run it in IDLE it works perfectly; however, if I run the script in the the terminal, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\calculator.py", line 1, in <module>
a,b = input('Enter a range: ').split('^')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You are running this in Python 2 instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are running it with python 2.

In python 2, `input` evaluates the input before returning, so it will return an int if you do what the prompt says.

Answer (score 0):

If it works correctly in IDLE but fails in the terminal then it’s very likely that the standard handler for python files is not set to Python 3 but Python 2. If you are calling the script directly, i.e. using just `./scriptname.py`, then the [*shebang*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) will determine which Python parser will be used to execute the script.

To use Python 3, add the following shebang line at the very beginning of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Note that this is also supported in Windows as per [PEP-397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/).